# htaccess redirect all files in the root directory to coresponding pages in subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have several pages in

```
http://localhost/template
```

like home.php, about.php, contact.php

In 
`http://localhost/template/sr` I have the pages with the same name.

This is what I have in my root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://localhost/template/sr/
```

My error.log file reports:

```
[localhost/sid#923dd8][rid#dd70b0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/template/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/template/
[localhost/sid#923dd8][rid#ddd0c8/subreq] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/template/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/template/index.php
[localhost/sid#923dd8][rid#ddb0c0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/template/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/template/
[localhost/sid#923dd8][rid#ddd0c8/subreq] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/template/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/template/index.php
```

This setup doesn't redirect I keep getting the pages from the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to redirect pages to coresponding pages in subdirectory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /template/sr/$1 [L]
```